# Remove duplicates with condition

Tags: r

I have the below data set

```
Data = data.frame(id =c(1,1), 
dob=c("06/06/2018", "06/06/2018"), 
reason=c("age", "disability"))
```

I need to delete all duplicate id's with reason as age

Tried the below but does work

```
Final_data = data[which(! duplicate (id)) & which( reason=="age"),]
```

Can someone help me I'm new to R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `which` returns the integer positions.  Instead the `&` can be applied directly on the logical conditions

```
Data[!duplicated(Data$id) &  Data$reason=="age",]
#  id        dob reason
#1  1 06/06/2018    age
```

#### Update

Based on the new data

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% f
   ilter(reason != "age"| n()==1)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups: id [3]
#     id dob        reason    
#  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     
#1  1.00 06/08/2018 disability
#2  2.00 08/08/1992 disability
#3  3.00 09/01/1995 age
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Data)[, .SD[reason != 'age'| .N == 1], id]
```

#### data

```
Data <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2, 2,3),
   dob=c("06/08/2018","06/08/2018", "08/08/1992", "08/08/1992", "09/01/1995"),
  reason= c("age","disability","age","disability","age"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Doesn't work it deletes all records with reason other than disability . I have multiple ids like this in my data where all the data is same except for the reason

Comment: Please update in your post.  You only showed the column names

Comment: This is my data set   = 1,1,2,3 dob="06/08/2018","06/08/2018", "08/08/1992", "08/08/1992, "09/01/1995" reason="age","disability",age","disability","age"

Comment: @UmangGureja Can you please update it in your post and also show the expected output

Comment: Output should be id = 1,2,3 dob= 06/08/2018, 08/08/1992,09/01/1995 reason= disability, disability, age

Comment: One id can multiple reason but reset of the data is same. If a id has a reason as age and disability i need to keep the disability record and delete the age record

Comment: @UmangGureja  Please check the example you commented`1, 1, 2, 3` is length 4 and `06/08/2018","06/08/2018", "08/08/1992", "08/08/1992, "09/01/1995"` is length 5

Comment: Sorry. This is my data set   = 1,1,2,2,3 dob="06/08/2018","06/08/2018", "08/08/1992", "08/08/1992, "09/01/1995" reason="age","disability",age","disability","age"

Answer (score 0):

In base-R:

```
Data[!(Data$dob %in% Data$dob[duplicated(Data$dob)] & Data$reason == "age"),]

  # id        dob     reason
  # 2  1 06/08/2018 disability
  # 4  2 08/08/1992 disability
  # 5  3 09/01/1995        age
```

**Data**

```
Data = data.frame( id = c(1,1,2,2,3), 
  dob=c("06/08/2018","06/08/2018", "08/08/1992", "08/08/1992", "09/01/1995"), 
reason= c("age","disability","age","disability","age"))
```

Comment: @UmangGureja May be it would be really good if you can add your final data-set and desired result to the question itself. It will be helpful to other user in future. Thx.